# How to check whether a timestamp is 10 minutes old?

Tags: java, timestamp, milliseconds

I have a timestamp `(searchTimestamp)` which I need to check whether it is less than 10 minutes old or not.

```
long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

long searchTimestamp = getTheTimestampFromURL();// this also gives me back timestamp in 13 digit (1425506040493)

long difference = Math.abs(currentTimestamp - searchTimestamp);

System.out.println(difference);

if (difference > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
    System.out.println("timestamp is greater than 5 minutes old");
}
```

I have got the above code which is working fine. Is this the right way to do this or is there any better way?

**NOTE:**

`getTheTimestampFromURL` will be older than the current timestamp in milliseconds always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that searchTimestamp > currentTimestamp so you don't need an abs and just use searchTimestamp - currentTimestamp.

Comment: Then how will it be 10 minutes old check?

Comment: That's still the same: so difference=searchTimestamp - currentTimestamp and you check if (difference > 10*60*1000). I'm actually not really sure if your "getTheTimestampFromURL" is really "newer" than the currentTimestamp, that of course depends on where you get it from. In any case you should know (otherwise you don't know what what the meaning of the difference is) so taking a Math.abs(..) should never make sense.

Comment: I updated that detail in my question regarding `getTheTimestampFromURL`.

Comment: Then difference=currentTimestamp-searchTimestamp, and check  if (difference > 10*60*1000)